# Does the arduino board have to be always physically connected to the electronic device you are running?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, electronics

If I have a basic electronic board with some LEDs and sound fx and I want to program them (I'm a beginner, learning about arduino), does the arduino board always have to be connected to the actual electronic board I'm running or is there a way to "upload" the programming to the circuit board?

Answer (score 2):

If the "basic electronic board" is programmable, then yes, you can upload a program to it.

In general, though, "some LEDs" and similar devices are not programmable, and without something to *drive* them (i.e., the Arduino) they won't do anything at all.  The Arduino is what has the program and it tells the "basic electronic board", moment by moment, what it should be doing.  It is the *brain* of the operation.  Remove the brain from someone and you'll find their body no longer functions.

Answer (score 0):

And Arduino UNO is basically a ATMega328 chip (with some extras) on a circuit board. So if you add an ATMega328 to your own circuitboard, you don't need an Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "Can I program the Arduino without anything else connected to it?", then yes, you can program it with out the sound and light board connected. But the program will start running shortly after the upload finishes.

If some devices were connected to it and some were not, it's possible the program won't function properly at that point (and obviously the not-connected devices won't function at all!), so you should make sure the Arduino can't or won't try to do anything to the few connected ones that might be harmful when some others are not connected, in case that is possible (this would be an unusual, but plausible, situation).